# Finding Scala libraries location from within Scala program

Tags: scala, classpath, program-entry-point

I'm trying to make one Scala program spawn another Scala program. I managed to obtain `java` executable from `System.getProperty("java.home")`, I've obtained some path from `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` (`sbt-launcher.jar` location), and with `ClassLoader` I've got `project/target/scala-2.11/classes` directory.

However, I am still unable to run it. JVM complain that it is unable to find Scala library's classes:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/concurrent/ExecutionContext
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
  at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I am looking for a way to add those files to classpath, but I want it to be portable. I do not look for solutions like hardcoding scala location on local computer nor do I want to use other environment variables and parameters than the one already existing. I also don't want to rely on SBT or Activators presence in user's environment.

Since the parent JVM process can use them their location has to be stored somewhere and I'll be thankful for help with finding out that location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To successfully spawn one Scala App from another I had to fix several issues with my code:

## 1. correct `main` class:

```
object ChildApp extends App {
  println("success")
}
```

to make sure that `ChildApp` is runnable by Java it has to be an `object`. Scala has no concept of `static` but object methods would (and main will) be compiled into static method.

## 2. correct class name:

While `ChildApp.getClass.getName` returns `ChildApp$`, it refers to an object (so that we could pass otherwise static-method-only class around). Java expects `$` in command line - in other works I had to remove tailing `$` before passing it into the process builder.

## 3. complete class path

I haven't found all used JARs within `System.getPropertiy("java.class.path")`:

```
val pcp = System getPropertiy "java.class.path" split File.pathSeparator // sbt-launcher.jar only
```

I haven't found them in `SystemClassLoader` either:

```
val scp = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader.asInstanceOf[URLClassLoader].getURLs.map(_.toString) // same as above
```

I did found compiled files from my project using Class' resources:

```
// format like jar:file:/(your-project/compiled.jar)!some/package/ChildApp.class
lazy val jarClassPathPattern  = "jar:(file:)?([^!]+)!.+".r
// format like file:/(your-project/compiled/some/package/ChildApp).class
lazy val fileClassPathPattern = "file:(.+).class".r

val jcp = jarClassPathPattern.findFirstMatchIn(pathToClass) map { matcher =>
  val jarDir = Paths get (matcher group 2) getParent()
  s"${jarDir}/*"
} toSet

val fcp = fileClassPathPattern.findFirstMatchIn(pathToClass) map { matcher =>
  val suffix   = "/" + clazz.getName
  val fullPath = matcher group 1
  fullPath substring (0, fullPath.length - suffix.length)
} toList
```

Finally I found where all those dependencies where stored:

```
// use App class' ClassLoader instead of system one
val lcp = ChildApp.getClass.getClassLoader.asInstanceOf[URLClassLoader].getURLs.map(_.toString)
```

## 4. bonus - JVM params and `java` location

```
val jvmArgs   = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean.getInputArguments.toList

lazy val javaHome = System getProperty "java.home"

lazy val java = Seq(
  Paths.get(javaHome, "bin", "java"),
  Paths.get(javaHome, "bin", "java.exe")
) filter (Files exists _) head
```

Then you have everything you need for `ProcessBuilder` / `Process`:

```
val executable = java.toString
val arguments  = jvmArgs ++ List("-cp", classPath, mainName) ++ mainClassArguments
```

PS. I checked several times - those *additional* JARs aren't passed using neither `CLASSPATH` environment variable nor with `-cp` parameter (`sbt-launcher.jar`'s MANIFEST file did't had anything as well). So anyone knowing how they are passed and why my solution actually works, please explain.